# Ошибка библиотеки telebot

Tags: python, telebot

```
...
File "\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 636, in get_updates
    return [types.Update.de_json(ju) for ju in json_updates]
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 636, in <listcomp>
    return [types.Update.de_json(ju) for ju in json_updates]
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 207, in de_json
    chat_boost = ChatBoost.de_json(obj.get('chat_boost'))
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 9152, in de_json
    obj['source'] = ChatBoostSource.de_json(obj['source'])
KeyError: 'source'
```

Вот такую ошибку выдает при запуске, при чем появилась она совершенно неожиданно, и есть как на компьютере, так и на хосте. Обновить библиотеку пробовал, ничего не изменилось. Помогите как-то исправить это недоразумение.

Comment: А сам код приложить забыли?